# Lots of IF statements in PHP?

Tags: php

We have 2 types of users, each type has his own page components when he opens the same page.
When I test it gives me the first compiled if statement although it's not for the same user type I;m using to test. I've been trying but I don't know where is the problem.
I had these components in separate pages but I found it's better to put details all together but I got stuck.

```
    <?php
           if(($userType[0] == 1))
            {
             if ($singleuseraddsnum != 0 ) {
               echo ' <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';
                        foreach($singleuseradds as $addsdata)
                        {
                          $adv_id = $addsdata['id'];

                          ?>  
                          }
                          
                          <tr>
                          <td><?= $addsdata['id']; ?></td>
                          <td>Request</td>
                          <td><?= $addsdata['pageurl']; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-info"><a href="adDetails.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id; ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Details </button></a></td>
                          <td class="text-danger"><a href="useracceptadd.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id ?>"><button class="btn btn-success"> Accept</button></a></td>
                          
                        </tr>

                        else if ($acceptedAddsNum != 0 ){
                        echo ' <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';
                        foreach($acceptedAddsData as $acceptedAddData)
                        {
                          $adv_id = $acceptedAddData['id'];                          
                          $hostlinksNum = $advertise->getAdsLinksForHostNum($conn,$user_id,$adv_id);
                          $hostlinks = $advertise->getAdsLinksForHost($conn,$user_id,$adv_id);
                          foreach($hostlinks as $links){
                            $hostlink = $links['link'];
                          }                      
                          <tr>
                          <td><?= $acceptedAddData['id']; ?></td>
                          <td>Accepted</td>
                          <td><?= $acceptedAddData['pagedescription'];?></td>
                          <td class="text-primary"><a href="adDetails.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id ?>" class="text-info"><button class="btn btn-primary">More</button></a></td>
                        </tr>
                            }
}
                    if (($userType[0] == 2)) {
                        if ($currentaddsnum !=0) {
                      echo '<table id="users">
                      <thead>
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>'; 
                          foreach($currentadds as $currentadd){
                            $add_id = $currentadd['id'];
                            $host_id = $user_id;
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                          <td><?= $currentadd['id']; ?></td>
                          <td style="color: #08e465">Started</td>
                          <td><?= $currentadd['pagename']; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-primary"><a href="adDetails.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id ?>" class="text-info"><button class="btn btn-primary">More</button></a></td>
                        }                     
                        if($row !=0){
                      echo '<table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';
                          foreach($userdata as $adddata){
                            $adv_id= $adddata['id'];
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                          <td><?= $adddata['id']; ?></td>
                          <td>Pending</td>
                          <td><?= $adddata['pageurl']; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-primary"><a href="adDetails.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id ?>" class="text-info"><button class="btn btn-primary">More</button></a></td>
                                                  
                            }
                        if($addhistorynum !=0){
                      echo '<table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>'; 
                          foreach($addhistory as $addhistorysingle){
                            $add_id = $addhistorysingle['id'];
                            $host_id = $user_id;
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                          <td><?= $addhistorysingle['id']; ?></td>  
                          <td>Finished</td>
                          <td><?= $addhistorysingle['pagename']; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-primary"><a href="adDetails.php?adv_id=<?= $adv_id ?>" class="text-info"><button class="btn btn-primary">More</button></a></td>
                          
                            }                  
                    }
          
                         
   <?php  
            
                }
                        }


           }
                            ?>
```

Comment: Loads of errors in that script with opening `<?php` and closing `?>` tags and brackets in the plain HTML code. Try to simplify your code, otherwise it will never work.

Answer (score 0):

As already someone suggested first get-rid spaghetti code. It can be made much better i.e. by using some templating engine, anyway, your sample can be simplified as well (code below) note that there are probably still errors like missing `</tr>`, `</tbody>` and `</table>`, however, you need to figure them out yourself as I have no input data to test. Lot of work to do.

```
<?php
if (($userType[0] == 1)) {
    if ($singleuseraddsnum != 0) {
        echo ' <table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>Ad ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';

        foreach ($singleuseradds as $addsdata) {
            $adv_id = $addsdata['id'];


            echo "<tr>
                <td>{$addsdata['id']}</td>
                <td>Request</td>
                <td>{$addsdata['pageurl']}</td>
                <td class='text-info'><a href='adDetails.php?adv_id={$adv_id}'><button class='btn btn-primary'>Details </button></a></td>
                <td class='text-danger'><a href='useracceptadd.php?adv_id={$adv_id}'><button class='btn btn-success'> Accept</button></a></td>

            </tr>";
        }
    } else
        $acceptedAddsNum = 1;
    if ($acceptedAddsNum != 0) {
        echo '<table class="table table-hover">
                      <thead class=" text-primary">
                      <th>Ad ID</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Details</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';

        foreach ($acceptedAddsData as $acceptedAddData) {
            $adv_id = $acceptedAddData['id'];
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedVariableInspection */
            $hostlinksNum = $advertise->getAdsLinksForHostNum($conn, $user_id, $adv_id);
            $hostlinks = $advertise->getAdsLinksForHost($conn, $user_id, $adv_id);
            foreach ($hostlinks as $links) {
                $hostlink = $links['link'];
            }

            echo "<tr>
                        <td>{$acceptedAddData['id']}</td>
                        <td>Accepted</td>
                        <td>{$acceptedAddData['pagedescription']}</td>
                        <td class='text-primary'><a href='adDetails.php?adv_id={$adv_id}' class='text-info'>
                                <button class='btn btn-primary'>More</button>
                            </a></td>
                    </tr>";

        }
    }
    if (($userType[0] == 2)) {

        if ($currentaddsnum != 0) {
            echo '<table id="users">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Ad ID</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>';

            foreach ($currentadds as $currentadd) {
                $add_id = $currentadd['id'];
                $host_id = $user_id;

                echo "<tr>
                <td>{$currentadd['id']}</td>
                <td style='color: #08e465'>Started</td>
                <td>{$currentadd['pagename']}</td>
                <td class='text-primary'><a href='adDetails.php?adv_id={$adv_id}' class='text-info'>
                        <button class='btn btn-primary'>More</button>
                    </a></td>";

            }

            if ($row != 0) {
                echo '<table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <th>Ad ID</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';

                foreach ($userdata as $adddata) {
                    $adv_id = $adddata['id'];

                    echo "<tr>
                    <td>{$adddata['id']}</td>
                    <td>Pending</td>
                    <td>{$adddata['pageurl']}</td>
                    <td class='text-primary'><a href='adDetails.php?adv_id={$adv_id}' class='text-info'>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary'>More</button>
                        </a></td>";

                }

                if ($addhistorynum != 0) {
                    echo '<table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead class=" text-primary">
                                <th>Ad ID</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th class="text-primary">Details</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';

                    foreach ($addhistory as $addhistorysingle) {
                        $add_id = $addhistorysingle['id'];
                        $host_id = $user_id;

                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>{$addhistorysingle['id']}</td>
                                <td>Finished</td>
                                <td>{$addhistorysingle['pagename']}</td>
                                <td class='text-primary'><a href='adDetails.php?adv_id={$adv_id}' class='text-info'>
                                        <button class='btn btn-primary'>More</button>
                                    </a></td>";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```